# How to fix "got multiple values for argument 'axis'" for Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.7

I was previously using the 'select' attribute for data frames, however that has been deprecated. Cannot find any specifics to the error I am receiving, any guidance/help would be much appreciated.

```
  df=df.loc(lambda x: not re.search('\d+_version_value', x), axis=1)
```

> Exception has occurred: TypeError
>   **call**() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the pandas documentation on deprecated [`select`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select.html):

> Deprecated since version 0.21.0: Use `df.loc[df.index.map(crit)]` to select via labels

So, try something like this:

```
df.loc[df.index.map(lambda x: not re.search('\d+_version_value', x))]
```

Or if you are trying to select columns:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.map(lambda x: not re.search('\d+_version_value', x))]
```

Example:

```py
print(df.head())

   sepalLength  sepalWidth  petalLength  petalWidth species
0          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
1          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
3          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
4          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

```py
df.loc[:, df.columns.map(lambda x: not re.search('Length', x))]

   sepalWidth  petalWidth species
0         3.5         0.2  setosa
1         3.0         0.2  setosa
2         3.2         0.2  setosa
3         3.1         0.2  setosa
4         3.6         0.2  setosa
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and not `loc`

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: not re.search('\d+_version_value', x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this -- square brackets for indexing:

```
  df=df.loc[lambda x: not re.search('\d+_version_value', x.column)]
```

Comment: I get the invalid syntax error. :/
                                                          
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Do you have a column to do the `re.search`?